# pip3 still locate package on python3.5/dist-packages while i have install already python 3.6

Tags: python, pip

when I tried to install some package using pip3  as follow;

```
pip3 install <somepacke>
```

I have found that this package  was still located on python 3.5, even I have install python 3.6 already. Here is my python 3.5 package  location;

`('/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages')`

Would you please let me know how to change pip3 default to `(‘/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages’)`?  so I can install this package on python 3.6

Comment: Do you have pip3.6? OTOH, you can also do `python3.6 -m pip` to ensure stuff gets installed to the python3.6 dirs. Eg, `python3.6 -m pip install some_package`. Even better: install to a virtual env.

Comment: @PM2Ring is right, better is `-m pip` args. also how many version of python installed and what is the output of `python3 -V`